# SQLite UTF-8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, sqlite

I try to run script (`.read FILE`) that has UTF-8 strings. I used pragma command:

```sql
PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";
```

But I get wrong characters.
If I create table and insert values by myself, everything works right.  What should I do to run script properly?

By the way, I checked a lot of questions/articles on stackoverflow and other resources + read documentation. I tried some methods, for example, to use `chcp 65001` in Windows `cmd` and then opened `sqlite3` in current window. But it didn't help.

Comment: There are three encodings you have to verify: the console encoding, the encoding the `sqlite3` program is working with (could be different from console encoding) and the encoding of the database (execute `PRAGMA encoding;` to check). I suspect that the strings are already mixed up before being presisted by sqlite. You could also check using Python, which can speak directly with an sqlite database (sqlite3 module).

Comment: @code_onkel I changed windows cmd encoding to UTF-8 `chcp 65001`, then changed db encoding `PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";`, then changed many time file encoding using Notepad++. Nothing works. I just changed bad characters to another bad charachers. Everything worked fine with Firebird database.

Comment: I think you should make a bit clearer, what you are acutally doing (which strings you are trying to insert, which language/encoding settings there are in your environment). I made a quick test on my German Win7 machine and was able to insert Umlaute (äöü) correctly without using `chcp` (verified via python).

Comment: @code_onkel I needed just to changle font to Lucida console. Rofl. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need to do is:

1. Open cmd and change encoding (`chcp 65001`)
2. Run sqlite3.exe from current windows
3. Change encoding (`PRAGMA encoding="UTF-8";`)
4. Create correct UTF-8 script.

Comment: The answer is obviously incorrect. See CL's answer or read [the documentation.](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding)

Answer (score 8):

The `PRAGMA encoding` setting does not change how you use the SQLite API. And the encoding of an existing DB cannot be changed.
Don't use it.

The `sqlite3.exe` command-line shell does not work with UTF-8 characters. (Except maybe in the latest version.)
Don't use it.

If your own scripts and applications use strings encoded in UTF-8, and if you use any tool *except* `sqlite3.exe` to check the resulting DB, then it will work.