# Sqlite3(terminal) can't correctly decode characters

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sqlite

I am following a tutorial where I was asked to create, insert and read data (and display it, using `ascii` mode) from the sqlite3 database.

However when I issue read command I get following output:
[image: output from terminal after reading from sqlite3 database]

When I paste it to text editor it yields `2GarfieldTabby18`

I am not sure whether is it sqlite3 itself, or rather terminal matter.Can anyone tell me what is the professional name of these square signs, why do they appear (I guess it has to do something with encoding), and how to fix them?

I'm running on Ubuntu 16.04. Sqlite version 3.11.0

Running `locale` in my terminal returns:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en_GB:en_AU:en_CA:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: I guess it is an encoding problem.  Take a look at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482132/sqlite-utf-8-encoding#38485232) and see if those answers fit your needs.  I'm not quite sure it's the same question.

Comment: How did you enter the data, and how are you reading it?  001F is the ASCII "unit separator" character.

Comment: This is correct behaviour for `sqlite3`'s `ascii` mode. Which tutorial?

Comment: @jgmh Thanks for the link but suggested answer does not seem to work, as @cl has suggested in the next answer after that one.

@varro I have inserted data using this command:
`INSERT INTO pets(_id, name, breed, gender, weight) VALUES(1, "Tommy", "Pomeranian", 1, 4);`. Then I used `.mode ascii` and after that I read data using `SELECT * FROM pets;`. But before I used `.mode ascii` I also read data and I got `1|Tommy|Pomeranian|1|4`.

@cl its Udacity's Android Basics Nanodegree. Lesson 1.27.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same thing. I'm following a training with Udacity and in the sqlite3 terminal I encounter the same thing. I'm also running Ubuntu 16.04 and my version of sqlite3 is also 3.11.0.

A solution, besides the one that you came up with of pasting it into an editor is the following:

In the sqlite3 terminal When requesting an .mode ascii response I get separator signs in the ascii text. In order to avoid those signs I need to enter after .mode ascii a .separator "" "" command before requesting the select * from pets; (pets.db) data base.

The only thing here is that it is repetitive. Every time one has to repeat the same line of code.

I'm wondering if there is a permanent solution to this.